# Handsontable - manually rerendering grid

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I wondering is it possible to call some method, to manually rendering grid in Handsontable ?
I need it, because after init, my first row has too big height. When I scroll the grid up and down, first row is rendered again properly. That's because ia have fixedRow, columns span and texts at first row cells are long.

I've tried Render() method but it didn't help. Only scrolling works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help, but it didn't work.
But I've solved the problem.

It was wrong meta configuration.
I have

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

content should be IE=10 or higher to proper Handsontable work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try calling updateSettings and render.

```
hotInstance.updateSettings({});
hotInstance.render();
```